# php while loop using wamp and sending csv to sql

Tags: php, sql, loops, csv, wamp

i have the following file:

```
<?php
require_once "conectar_a_base_de_dados.php";
$file = "todos_cp.csv";

if( file_exists($file) )
{
$fh = fopen($file, "r");

while ($line = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ";"))
{
$id_d = $line[0];
$id_c = $line[1];
$id_f = $line[2];
$freg = $line[3];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO freguesias (codigo_distrito, codigo_concelho, codigo_freguesia, freguesias)
VALUES('$id_d','$id_c','$id_f','$freg')");
}

fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

which is intended to send data to the database but i am getting only zeros 0 on the $freg column and i can't figure out why!
i am using wamp server if that matters

here is a little bit of the csv file:

```
01;01;249;Alcafaz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;011;AGADÃO
01;01;250;Caselho;;;;;;;;;;;3750;012;AGADÃO
01;01;251;Corga da Serra;;;;;;;;;;;3750;013;AGADÃO
01;01;252;Foz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;014;AGADÃO
01;01;253;Guistola;;;;;;;;;;;3750;015;AGADÃO
```

Comment: I'm assuming there are newline characters after those "AGADÃO" values?  I ran this code on my computer and it works fine.  Instead of inserting into MySQL, try using print_r($line) to see what you're getting.

Comment: i will try that now...

Comment: yes there are newline

Comment: it returns a lot of mixed arrays!

Comment: print_r($line[0]); gives me the correct values for $id_d

Comment: print_r($line) gives me this: <pre>Array
(
    [0] => 01
    [1] => 01
    [2] => 249
    [3] => Alcafaz
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
    [14] => 3750
    [15] => 011
    [16] => AGADÃO
)</pre>

Comment: yes, to me it gives the same, i just printed print_r($line[3]); and there is the text returned!

Comment: sould i make a separated sql loop ? but the other info is being inserted to the sql!!!

Comment: Print the value of $freg to make sure it's there in PHP. If it is, then perhaps the MySQL database column's type is the problem.

Comment: seems like nobody knows the answer for this question :/

Comment: it prints the text like print_r($line[3]); did

Comment: Yeah, so it might be a database problem. What is the schema of frequencies? "desc freguencias" in MySQL prints this. Perhaps the column type can't hold the kind of data you're putting in there.

Comment: you are right, it was a database problem